# On the iPhone, is it possible for a touchesBegan:withEvent to fire while a CADisplayLink callback method is executing?

Tags: iphone, events, cadisplaylink

Wouldn't the touchesBegan:withEvent always fire "before" or "after" each iteration of the CADisplayLink callback?

Edit: Here's my CADisplayLink instantiation:

```
CADisplayLink *aDisplayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(tick:)];
[aDisplayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the display link is connected to the main run loop then yes — it would be impossible for the two to occur at the same time. Cocoa's run loops queue up messages to send, then send them one at a time.

Comment: I added my CADisplayLink code to the question. If that code were in my app delegate that would be main run loop correct?

Comment: Assuming you're performing that on the main thread (which, if you haven't done anything special, you are) then yes — it'll feed into the main run loop.